# How to outset faces evenly

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to get familiar with Blender's inset tool and having trouble to produce an even outset on a U shaped mesh. What I would like to achieve (using 3ds Max):

[image]

What happens when I use *Outset* in Blender:

[image]

For some reason the faces are stretched horizontally at the top of the U shape. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: What do you want to achieve with Outset in this case? If you want to move insetted faces upwards at once don't use Outset. Use Depth parameter of Inset command (Ctrl to tweak)

Comment: The goal would be to have the mesh grow wider in height as seen here https://i.imgur.com/PefoayH.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: final]

Everything is working just fine.

Try to **Remove Doubles**, and double check your mesh for any errors. Also **Apply Scale** to it.

Here is whole process.

1. **Select All** - <kbd>A</kbd>.
2. Press <kbd>I</kbd> for **Inset**.
3. Move mouse to get wanted offset.
4. Move created geometry along Z axis - <kbd>G</kbd>><kbd>Z</kbd>.

[image: gif]

### Edit for incremental height:

First of all you will want to use different topology for this case to prevent faces becoming non-planar after couple of insets.

[image: topo]

Than you should follow simple procedure: **Inset** <kbd>I</kbd> > **Extrude** <kbd>E</kbd> and repeat as much as you want/will be able to.

[image: editgif]

### Edit 2:

No, there is no easy or efficient way to do this by outseting whole shape or extruding outwards.

You can make the biggest step, than inset to the smallest and after that start outseting from the smallest (bigger loops first), like so:

[image: edit2gif]

As you can see this method is quite strange and after this you will need to select each loop and extrude it individually.

Comment: I think I've got the inset working, but when I try to outset faces they end up uneven. I've updated the question.

Comment: I would like to create a U shaped mesh which grows incrementally wider in height. In 3ds Max it would look something like this:  https://i.imgur.com/PefoayH.png

Comment: Great, this works. In terms of convenience it would be nice if there was a way to achieve the same result starting from the opposite side, but I take it that's not easily possible?

Comment: @helmi77 Check second edit. It's not recommended method, it's not even good method but still this is another option.

Comment: Yes, seems a little unintuitive, but the first method should work perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: When using inset you don't need to move the faces as a separate command. Just change the value for depth within the inset tool. https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOaqb.gif

Answer (score 1):

Am I missing something or could you not achieve the same thing by using the bevel tool? Just select the edges you want to create that angle on, hit ctrl+B and move your mouse to increase/decrease the bevel. Use your scrollwheel to decrease the number of faces being created.