# Offset Function?

Tags: modeling, mesh

In Adobe Illustrator, there is a function called offset path. It's particularly useful when you want to create a uniform outline around an irregularly shaped object because simply scaling it often doesn't yield desirable results. The picture below illustrates my point
[image: Scaling Vs. Offset]

I'm looking for a similar function in blender that will allow me to select a closed mesh and produce a duplicate that is offset some degree from the original. How is this conventionally done?

Thanks so much!

Comment: This should get you started: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/101324/outline-that-follows-character

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48152/is-there-a-way-to-inset-in-the-opposite-direction-not-outset and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61430/how-to-use-the-outset-option-from-the-inset-command/61431#61431 or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/98518/how-to-outset-faces-evenly and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76628/how-to-outset-from-edges-vertices or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1088/is-there-a-way-to-offset-an-edge-extrude-edge-loop-perpendicular-to-each-edge

Comment: ... and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38781/how-to-add-outline-to-text ... and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36862/outline-bezier-curve-in-2d-mode